# Convert Ruby to C# / validate signature with a private key sha256

Tags: c#, ruby

I am creating a web API to receive a webhook from TradeGecko and they are sending a signature to validate the content.
I need to check if the body request is valid by checking the signature sent. They provided a ruby code, however, I've tried to code to check and it is not working. (https://developer.tradegecko.com/docs.html#webhooks)

body = "{"object_id":111142999,"event":"order.create","timestamp":1611115523,"resource_url":"https://api.tradegecko.com/orders/111142999.json"}"

application.secret = mugBoXMvb289zISbmcqKl0DYFMZzErpRfls2dYxBvJA

ruby code:

```
def generate_signature(body)
  digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
  Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, application.secret, body.to_json)).strip
end
```

C# code

```
        string body = "{\"object_id\":111142999,\"event\":\"order.create\",\"timestamp\":1611115523,\"resource_url\":\"https://api.tradegecko.com/orders/111142999.json\"}";
        JObject bodyjson = JObject.Parse(body);
        string Signature = "0SWDkYvqAoEiJdK + l6vaMjG1IKCvHekMdjdHr + Tt2IY =";

        // Convert signature to byte array in order to compute the hash
        byte[] bSignature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);

        // Convert ApiKey to byte array - for initializing HMACSHA256
        byte[] bSecretKey2 = Convert.FromBase64String(Signature);
        byte[] bSecretKey = Convert.FromBase64String("mugBoXMvb289zISbmcqKl0DYFMZzErpRfls2dYxBvJA=");

        string strSignature = "";
        using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(bSecretKey))
        {
            // Compute signature hash
            byte[] bSignatureHash = hmac.ComputeHash(bSignature);

            // Convert signature hash to Base64String for transmission
            strSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(bSignatureHash);
        }

        bool isvalidade = (Signature == strSignature);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably best not to post your application secret on a public website.

Comment: Thank you, Martin, this secret is from our dev environment and easily destroyed, but thank you though.